# Laravel Query Builder: How to access JSON key/value pair

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Using *Laravel 5.1*, how can I access a JSON key/value pair via Query Builder in a migration? There is JSON data stored in **json_data_column** that I need to validate in a **where()** Query Builder expression. Logic is such :

```
DB::transaction(function () {

 echo 'Deleting rows where user_id is empty...' . PHP_EOL;

 DB::table('payment_methods')->where('json_data_column->user_id', '""')->delete();

});
```

However, chaining does not seem to work here. Indeed, output is:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                          
  SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist           
  LINE 1: ... "payment_methods" where "json_data_column"->user_id...                    
                                                               ^ (SQL: delete from "payment_me  
  thods" where "payment_platform_data"->user_id = "")
```

Is it possible to use chaining using the logic up there in this case? If not, how can I access the JSON fields?

Comment: Please share your db structure and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `user_id` in single quotes, or else it is treated like an identifier:

```
 DB::table('payment_methods')->where("json_data_column->>'user_id'", '')->delete();
```

Comment: Error :
  *[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                          
  SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown        
  LINE 1: ...ethods" where "json_data_column"->'user_id' = $1                       
                                                                     ^                          
  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explic  
  it type casts. (SQL: delete from "payment_methods" where "json_data_column"->'user_id' = "")*

Comment: @leym  I made a change to dereference `user_id` as text instead of json and use an empty string for comparison.  Please see if that works.

Comment: I now get a foreign key constraint violation error message, which indicates me that... it works! Thank you! Now I have another problem up my sleeve :)